# How to prevent moving focus to non modal dialog if a button in this dialog is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, focus

How to prevent moving focus to non modal dialog if a button in this dialog is clicked? The dialog itself contains focusable components (text field) but clicking on one particular button should just trigger the action leaving the focus on the component in another window where it was before.

In other words, window should not gain focus if user clicks on a particular button inside.

Comment: Could you post your code and describe what you have tried to do?

Answer (score 3):

Since JDK 7 you should be able to use:

```
dialog.setAutoRequestFocus( false );
```

In earlier versions:

```
dialog.setFocusableWindowState( false );
dialog.setVisible( true );
dialog.setFocusableWindowState( true );
```

The user will still be able to click on the window, but it should not gain focus when first displayed.

Edit:

```
button.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: In my case window should not gain focus if user clicks on a particular button inside.

Comment: @dpolivaev, see edit. If it doesn't help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem.